# Finding index of an item in C#List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project where I need to find the index of an item in my C# List and and the following 3 indexes.

For example:

I want to find the index of 'Mary' in my name List:

Joseph
Mary
John
Peter
Andrew

After I find the index of Mary I want to add the following 3 indexes (John, Peter, Andrew) and store them in an array.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Did you make any try to find out, how we find the index of an item in a C# list? I am pretty sure that If you google it you would find millions of results. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `indexOf` method on `List<T>` to find the index of the first matching item:

```
var items = new List<string> { "Joseph", "Mary", "John", "Peter", "Andrew" };

var indexOfMary = items.IndexOf("Mary");

var itemAtIndexOfMary = items[indexOfMary];
```

Once you've done that you can then index into the list (the last line of code) at any point to retrieve the item at that position.

Answer (score 0):

`int index = myList.IndexOf("Mary");`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.